# Mostrar Imagem em um <p:dataTable> com primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, spring-boot, maven, xhtml

Como salvar e mostrar as imagens ou PDF que foram salvo no BD (Não é um caminho, é do tipo  **byte[]** ) em um <p:dataTable> usando spring boot(2.9)? Consigo salvar no BD, mas na hora de mostrar não sai nada.

Minha Entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Documento implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;    

private byte[] rgFoto;
private byte[] cpfFoto;

    /* GET / SET */
}
```

Form que salva no BD:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">                  
    <div class="card card-primary card-outline ">                               
        <div class="card-header">                                                   
            <h:outputLabel value="Documentação" /> 
        </div>
    <div class="card-body">                                 
        <p:outputLabel value="Inscrição no cadastro de pessoa física (CPF):" />
        <br />
        <p:fileUpload id="fotoCPF" label="Escolha imagem..." value="#{documentoController.cpfFoto}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.pdf"/>
        <br /><br />
        
        <p:outputLabel value="Identificação com foto ( RG/CNH/Conselho Profissional):" />
        <br />
        <p:fileUpload id="fotoRG" label="Escolha imagem..." value="#{documentoController.rgFoto}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.pdf"/>      

        <div style="display: flex;justify-content: flex-start;" class="divBotao">
            <p:fragment>
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" class="voltar"/>
            </p:fragment>
            <p:commandButton value="Enviar Documentos" class="btn-laranja" action="#{documentoController.doUpload()}" update="@form, messages" ajax="false" style="margin-left: 10px"/>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

// Metodo que faz o upload das imagens e salva

```
public void doUpload() throws IOException {
    try {
    // SALVA O CPF
    UploadedFile uploadedCpfFoto = getCpfFoto();        
    // SALVA O RG
    UploadedFile uploadedRGFoto = getRgFoto();
    byte[] CPF = (IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedCpfFoto.getInputStream()));
    byte[] RG = (IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedRGFoto.getInputStream()));

    documento.setCpfFoto(CPF);
    documento.setRgFoto(RG);
    
    documentoRepository.save(documento);
    
    documento = new Documento();
    Mensagens.info("Salvo com sucesso", "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }
}
```

// Metodo que busca lista

```
public void consultaSolicitacoes() {
    try {
        listDocumento = documentoRepository.findAll();
    if (listDocumento == null) {
        Mensagens.info("Não foram localizados registros", "");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Mostrar uma lista que vem do BD com as imagens (Não tá aparecendo as imagens):

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Lista" action="#{documentoController.consultaSolicitacoes()}" update="messages" ajax="false"/>
</h:form>

<p:dataTable value="#{documentoController.listDocumento}"
    paginator="true" rows="10" var="certidao"
    emptyMessage="Nenhuma certidão encontrada!"
    paginatorPosition="bottom">

    <p:column headerText="ID" style="width: 15%;">      
        <h:outputText value="#{documento.id}" />
    </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="CPF" style="width: 15%;">
            <!-- Exibindo a imagem usando p:graphicImage ou outra coisa -->                     
            <p:graphicImage value="#{certidao.cpfFoto}" contentType="image/jpeg" />
        </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="RG" style="width: 15%;">
        <!-- Exibindo a imagem usando p:graphicImage ou outra coisa -->                     
        <p:graphicImage value="#{certidao.rgFoto}" />   
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```